# The model presented or the presented model?

Tags: adjectives

For example, when referencing the model we presented in the paper,

> The presented model is helpful to many other related
>   researches.

or

> The model presented is helpful to many other related
>   researches.

If it is `proposed`, I think both is OK, and `proposed model` might be slightly better in academic writing? What about `presented`?

I also see sentences like

> The model presented in this section gives a brief introduction on the
>   use of the COMSOL ECRE Version.

Comment: I think both are fine, though "the model presented" is probably (slightly) more idiomatic. You might even be able to drop *presented* altogether, especially if you're not talking about models that you *didn't* present.

Comment: "Related researches" is also not quite on target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The presented model" - There's only one model, which is presented

"The model presented" - There are several models, and you're talking about the one that is presented

Comment: I don't think that split is fully justified. You could even swap the descriptions depending on the context.